# Qt threading, Crash from the destructor of the QObject moved

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt4, qthread

I'm trying to move a connection handler (containing a QTCPSocket object) to a separate thread from the QMainWindow object.

So far it works, but if I close the QMainWindow, It crashes and I receive the following:

> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 1680d0. Receiver '' (of type 'QAbstractSocket') was created in thread 34fe0c"

Here is my code:
in the QMainWindow constructor (subclassed):

```
QThread m_commsThread;
m_pICommsHandler = new CommsHandlerIP();
m_pICommsHandler->moveToThread(&m_commsThread);
// when it starts, we start the connection
connect(&m_commsThread,SIGNAL(started()),m_pICommsHandler,SLOT(connectToHost()));
m_commsThread.start();
```

in the QMainWindow destructor:

```
m_commsThread.quit();
m_commsThread.wait();
delete m_pICommsHandler;
```

About CommsHandlerIP.cpp

```
CommsHandlerIP::CommsHandlerIP() {
m_TCPSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
}

CommsHandlerIP::~CommsHandlerIP(void)
{
m_TCPSocket->deleteLater(); // It's going to crash a bit later if I have this line
}
```

m_TCPSocket should be in the right thread to be deleted but I feel like by closing the main thread, the affinity has become messy.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two things happening:

1. As far as i remember, there were always some issues with Qt4 when calling `moveToThread()` on a `QAbstractSocket`.
2. When you call `deleteLater()` on your socket, the thread in which it lives is already stopped.

A possible solution could be to subclass your `CommsHandlerIP` from `QThread` and override `run()`:

```
CommsHandlerIP::CommsHandlerIP() :
    QThread(),
    m_TCPSocket(0)
{
    moveToThread(this);
}

void CommsHandlerIP::run()
{
    m_TCPSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connectToHost();

    exec();

    m_TCPSocket->close();
    delete m_TCPSocket;
}
```